# Remove Gmail "send mail as" for former employee

Tags: gmail

A place I do some work for has lost an employee recently. I've removed his email account from our server after having a courtesy auto-responder for a while, but I've realised he has a Gmail account which is configured to "send mail as" his work address.

I would like to be able to remove his ability to send email from the work domain, but I don't have access to his Gmail account to remove the setting.

Does Google offer any mechanism or recourse for this situation? He can continue to send mail under the banner of our domain name even though he has ceased to work at the company as long as this setting persists.

Answer (score 12):

I worked it out.

In the original email that Gmail sent out to the external address in order to "verify" it there was the following section:

> If you accidentally clicked the link,
>   but you do not want to allow
>   xxx@yyy.com to send messages using
>   your address, click this link to
>   cancel this verification:
>   https://mail.google.com/mail/blahblahblahblahblah

I found it just by grepping his maildir, clicked the link and it said he can no longer send using his work address.

I realise you can just spoof the "from" headers willy-nilly, but you have to be technically savvy enough to know that this is possible and 99% of my users are not, including this one.

Comment: Nice solution -- fortunate that this user hadn't deleted that message.

Comment: Yeah, it was a nervous minute as I waited for the grep to run :)

Comment: Erf, is there any way to do that if you don't have access to this email anymore?

Comment: Thanks a lot.. yes it did worked.. I just searched for emails from mail-noreply@google.com and i found the verification email which was send to my company domain's email to ask for verification.. and there was a link to cancel the verification.. i just clicked that link and now my employee can't use "email as" option of my domain. That is a great post.. thanks a lot again..

Comment: @Shabbyrobe I think you could mark this answer as a correct one.. so it will stop popping up :)

Answer (score 7):

Does he really send mail using your domain? Or is it just the reply-to adress that is set in his gmail account? The first you can prevent by just removing his mailbox, the second you can't. Even I could send email using one of your emailadresses as reply-to adress.

Comment: Yup, it's a feature of email as such that this is possible. I think this needs to be handled outside the electronic world - try the diplomatic one, and if it throws an exception, try the legal ;-)